Kafka message processed by multiple instances of the same application all in the same consumer group
I am processing kafka messages in spark streaming. My topic has 2 partitions and one consumer group. Error condition lead to 3/4 or more instances of the same application running, all in the same consumer group and listening to the same topic. The message was posted to a single partition, but all the 3 instances of the application got that same message, and the message was processed 3 times. This caused 3 times the number of records in the database, duplicates etc.
Ideally only one instance of the kafka-spark-streaming job is supposed to be running. Some error conditions lead to multiple instances running.
I validated the partitions, consumer groups etc. I would like to understand why the same message was processed by all the 3 instances of the application and how to avoid this going forward. I now have set up a cron job to ensure that there is only one instance of the kafka-spark-streaming application running and if there are more than one, additional instances will be killed.
Spark streaming job is running in Hadoop on Yarn.
